# Property undefined when calling a function from another class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I created this sample code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. [Run this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQLYE8BqYIArgKbQC80A5AC4kQ0CMATAMxUDc6mARogFzQAQoi7cMweADsGAJyLAa8WQAo%208QSPgBKFOMwYaACwCWEAHTqK0dVwMBfVPqwks8WESnAVutAYPGZpaI5mBS8MYksh5eNCbSKoEWuDGK8VLadpiOzjipcQm%20%20gaSMvAgJOYg8ADmiabJ%20ISkmfqOOaCQMFp6BmERRlH56SoAZp7Agj4UAHzQAG7wJgAmRf6Y414%20WRjtTqUM0KOI1lIkAO5wiCpnl1o%20rcfw5i5uqdtAA).

Cannot read property 'myValue' of undefined

```js
class Foo {
    myValue = 'test123';
    boo: Boo;

    constructor(boo: Boo) {
        this.boo = boo;
    }

    memoFunc() {
        this.boo.anotherFunction(this.myFunction);
    }

    myFunction() {
        console.log(this.myValue);
    }
}

class Boo {
    anotherFunction(func: () => void) {
        func();
    }
}

const foo = new Foo(new Boo());
foo.memoFunc();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either use `bind` or use an `arrow function` to get the correct `this` value.

**Bind :-**

```
 memoFunc() {
        this.boo.anotherFunction(this.myFunction.bind(this));
    }
```

**Arrow function :-**

```
 memoFunc() {
        this.boo.anotherFunction(()=>this.myFunction());
    }
```